# Problem with the request body with node.js/express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem and dunno how to solve this. I tried some recommendations online but nothing worked.

Heres the Problem. I want to create a Rest-API with the common HTTP methods. As I tested it, it throw an "message": "ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'ID' cannot be null" - Error (useing Postman).

```
error:  Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'ID' cannot be null
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
at Connection.query (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
at Function.Customer.create (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\app\models\customer.model.js:13:9)
at exports.create (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\app\controllers\customer.controller.js:26:14)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\rozan\source\repos\Diplomarbeit\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12) {
```

code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
errno: 1048,
sqlMessage: "Column 'ID' cannot be null",
sqlState: '23000',
index: 0,
sql: 'insert into customer set `id` = NULL, `name` = NULL, `address` = NULL, `email` = NULL, `tel` = NULL, `isprivate` = true'
}

After some time I found the problem.

```
console.log("ID: " + req.body.ID);

//Create Customer
const customer = new Customer ({
    ID: req.body.ID,
    Name: req.body.Name,
    Address: req.body.Address,
    EMail: req.body.EMail,
    Tel: req.body.Tel,
    isprivate: req.body.isprivate
});

console.log("ID: " + customer.ID);
```

The object ID in customer is null, but I declared it clearly.
Here is my server.js code in which I declared express.json() and express.urlencoded().

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ 
    extended: true 
}));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Willkommen im Backdoor." })
})

require("./app/routes/customer.router.js")(app);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server laeuft auf Port 3000");
})
```

Thanks.

[Added]

Here's the asked Postman HTTP-POST method. I send the data raw and in json.

```
{
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "testname",
    "Address": "testaddresse",
    "EMail": "testemail",
    "Tel": "telefontest",
    "isprivate": true
}
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsb4hf9wyf6ftzs/Diplomarbeit.zip?dl=0) ist the whole project on dropbox

Here is the MySQL DB structure:

```
create table if not exists customer (
    ID int primary key,
    Name varchar(32),
    Address varchar(64),
    Email varchar(64),
    Tel varchar(16),
    isprivate boolean
);

create table if not exists contract (
    RID int primary key,
    KID int references customer,
    eintrageDatum date
);
```

Comment: How are you calling your endpoint with postman?
For what I can see, you have no post method on you route, so you cannot receive that from the client to create a new client.

Comment: can you log "req.body" and add it to the question

Comment: Have added your request

Comment: You error on the database side as `mysql` throws the error.
The issue is that the`req.body` is empty so the Customer has null on every property.
Can you send the post handling function?

Comment: Please show your actual code as [mcve], because right now your server doesn't do what you say it does: there is no `app.post()` so whatever your problem is, it has nothing to do with the server code you're showing.

Comment: I uploaded the whole project onto my dropbox

Comment: It'd be better to include the relevant code/config in the question, including the middleware stack around body parsing.